# How not to save specific programs in Windows 10 Timeline feature?

Tags: windows-10, timeline

I want to set some programs like Chrome or Skype so that they will not appear in the Windows 10 Timeline feature, without turning it (the Timeline) off in the privacy setting. Is it possible?

Comment: In the past Shawn Brink has authored a tutorial on how to customize every prominent Windows 10 feature, but a few months ago he said that "[I'm not aware of a way to have exclusions for Timeline.](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/100703-open-use-timeline-windows-10-a.html)"